# How to show the "active" instead of "first child"?

Tags: html, css

I'm still trying to learn css and html here :P Anyway I got this code from this site http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_topnav maybe you guys are familiar

```
...
    @media screen and (max-width:680px) {
      ul.topnav li:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
      ul.topnav li.icon {
        float: right;
        display: inline-block;
      }
    }
...
```

I wanted to show the one that is **active** instead of the **first-child**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be done by adding class **active** inside **:not** ,

```
@media screen and (max-width:680px) {
      ul.topnav li:not(.active) {display: none;}
      ul.topnav li.icon {
        float: right;
        display: inline-block;
      }
}
```

But the active class is not getting added to the selected item in the given example I guess.

**Update**
Please see this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/arshadmuhammed/Lpuv6pwc/4/ to see how it is done. And please note that I have made some changes in CSS and included jQuery and added some javascript too.

**CSS Modification**

```
li.active {
  background: red;
}
```

**HTML Modification**
Instead of giving active class to `a` tag I have given it to the `li` itself,

```
<li class="active"><a href="#news">News</a></li>
```

**Added javascript/jQuery code**

```
$('#myTopnav li').click(function() {
  $('#myTopnav li').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

This will make the selected menu active.

Comment: That is because the active class is not being added to the selected menu item. You should fix that first. You might wanna write some javascript code if you are using the example you mentioned in your question.

Comment: I just used the exact same code as the w3school has given as an example. There is already an active class

Comment: Please see the updated answer @JaneDoe and tell me if you have any doubt

Answer (score 1):

Just change `:first-child` for `:active`

**EDIT**
Sorry I didn't understand you correctly. I'm making a fiddle to demonstrate how to do it.